# Get entire HTML, not just text with Goutte

Tags: php, html, laravel, guzzle, goutte

I'm parsing a website and I have a problem, because it has some text split up with `<br>`, but when I use `$node->text()`, there's not even a space in place of that `<br>`.

How can I do to get the `<br>` too or at least replace it with a space?

The HTML is something like this:

`<span>Some<br>Text</span>`

Currently I get `SomeText` and I want it to be `Some Text`;

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the HTML for that node instead of the text, and replace the `<br>` tags with spaces yourself. Something like this should do just fine:

```
str_replace('<br>', ' ', strip_tags($node->html(), '<br>'));
```

The `strip_tags` is there to remove anything that's not `<br>`, so it would be the equivalent of the `text()` method, but allow the line break tags. Then they can be replaced with spaces using `str_replace`. The above will transform this:

```
<span>Some<br>Text</span>
```

into this

```
Some Text
```

Comment: That's great. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

With Goutte you can use the `html()` method.

```
$node->html();
```

It will include the `<br/>` though. You could then use a `strip_tags` to remove the html tags.

```
$text = strip_tags($node->html());
```

There is probably a built in way of doing this with Goutte.